# When did Nuremberg adopt the Gregorian Calendar?

Tags: germany, calendar, holy-roman-empire

A similar question has been posed on this site in the past, ["When did Frankfurt am Main adopt the Gregorian Calendar?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/27580/when-did-frankfurt-am-main-adopt-the-gregorian-calendar). I'm trying to discern exactly when the city of Nuremberg adopted the Gregorian Calendar but haven't found a definitive answer yet.

Bavaria as a whole has a tradition of [Catholic faith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bavaria#Religion). Can we assume that Nuremberg adopted the Gregorian Calendar [at 1583](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adoption_of_the_Gregorian_calendar#Timeline) along with the other Catholic states of the Holy Roman Empire? I would like to base my answer upon facts and not the assumptions I've made above if possible.

Comment: Nuremburg was a Free Imperial City in 1583 and so there is no guarantee that it would have the same Catholic religion as Bavaria.  Don't assume that a German city belonged to a principality - in this case Nuremburg was itself a state of the empire.

Comment: Nuremberg adopted Protestantism in 1525, thanks to Osiander and Lazarus Spengler, and thus was part of the Corpus Evangelicorum in the Regensburg Reichstag. So it's quite likely that Nuremberg followed the 1699 proposal of the Reichstag regarding the calendar reform in 1700 (just as comment since i can't provide any sources yet...)

Comment: Additional note: technically, the Nuremberg Council may in fact have **adopted**  the Reichstag's recommendation in 1699. Its **implementation** may be a different question. Often, the calendar was adapted by leaving out 11 days in february 1700, so that march 1st followed on february 18.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this source](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Julian_and_Gregorian_Calendars), Nürnberg adopted the calendar in 1699:

Comment: I've accepted this answer. The additional information provided in the comments to my question add deeper contextual information and further support the answer provided, thank you.

Comment: I suggest incorporating your 18:31 comment. It is valuable information. Comments are short lived or can “drown” in a sea of comments.

Comment: @Ludi: actually, it's not my comment. You're most welcome to edit the relevant comments with attribution into the answer if you feel it  would improve it.